# Allowing a Macintosh application to write files

Tags: macos, dmg

We market an application that runs on multiple platforms, including Macintosh.  On the Macintosh the software gets packaged into a .dmg file, and when installed everything goes into the /Applications hierarchy.

Some of the files in our application's hierarchy are samples that users are supposed to be able to modify in place or copy to different files in the same directory.  The problem is the permissions that seem to get applied within the /Applications hierarchy prevent our application from doing such operations.

So I either need to change the install so the directories and files in question within /Applications allow modification, or I need to segregate the sample files to a different location on the disk where they can be modified.

I've tried making sure the permissions on the files allow writing at the time the .dmg file is pulled together, but then when the product is installed the permissions get changed to more restrictive ones that don't allow file modification or copying.

I've been able to modify the packaging so the sample files get installed to a different location, but so far I haven't been able to find a suitable area on the Macintosh disk to put them so modification is allowed.  I haven't been able to figure out how to tell the packaging that these sample files should be installed into the installer's home directory.

Anyone have any suggestions?  I'm afraid I'm a bit of an Apple novice.  The procedure to build the .dmg file employs a Makefile that invokes commands like pkgbuild and productbuild.  The productbuild command uses a --distribution qualifier that references a .xml file.  There don't seem to be any scripts invoked.

Comment: You need first to clarify whether your app is running in its own sandbox or not before I can answer your question. Second thing I need to know is whether your app is properly signed by a valid Developer ID certificate. Finally, I need to know what are the macOS's you are targeting. Without this info, it is hard to give you a valid answer.

Comment: Can you explain what "running in its own sandbox" means?  I'm not aware that the product is signed by any kind of certificate.  We're targeting macOS 10.10.5 or later.

Comment: Any app that is distributed via Mac App Store must be sandboxed. See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

Comment: In addition, your app should be signed with a certificate for Gateway to let you run the app once you download it from the internet. If you are not distributing it via Mac App Store, you need to get a Developer ID certificate in order to sign it. For that you need to be a registered developer at developer.apple.com.